# onchange function using select option not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

`onchange` event function not work using select option.
I am create a `getval` function.

```js
$('.name-list').css('display', 'block');
// $(".name-list").change(function(){
function getval(sel) {
  var select_list = $(sel).text();
  $(".target").val(select_list);
  event.preventDefault();
  //Selecte list then hide
  $('.name-list').css('display', 'none');
  getcodenamefun();
  $(".next-focus").focus();
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
  <input type="text" name="ccode" class="td-size target" autocomplete="off" onkeydown="get(this.value);">
  <select class="form-control name-list" name="codelist" id="data" style="display: none;" onchange="getval(this.value);">
    <option value="1">15170</option>
    <option value="2">15490</option>
    <option value="3">11070</option>
  </select>
</td>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working with this code?

Comment: You appear to be trying to use the select elements `value` as a selector in `$(sel).text()`, which doesn't seem intentional, are you trying to convert it to a string?

Comment: You are passing the value and acting like it is the DOM element..... Simple console.log() in your code would have shown you your problem.  `function getval(sel) { console.log(sel, $(sel).length);` Console.log is your friend, learn to use it to look into the code.

Comment: `onchange="getval(this.value);"` -> `onchange="getval(this);"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.name-list').css('display', 'block');
// $(".name-list").change(function(){
function getval(sel) {
  var select_list = $(sel).val()
  $(".target").val(select_list);
  event.preventDefault();
  //Selecte list then hide
  $('.name-list').hide();
  //getcodenamefun();
  $(".next-focus").focus();
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
  <input type="text" name="ccode" class="td-size target" autocomplete="off" onkeydown="get(this);">
  <select class="form-control name-list" name="codelist" id="data" style="display: none;" onchange="getval(this);">
    <option value="1">15170</option>
    <option value="2">15490</option>
    <option value="3">11070</option>
  </select>
</td>
```

`onchange="get(this)"` and on javascript `$(sel).val()` will fix your problem.

To hide an element you can use `hide()` method instead of changing it's style property. `$(selector).hide()` and `$(selector).show()`